# Find the derivative of $\frac{\cos^{-1} (x)} {x}$ by first principle?

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives, trigonometry

$$\frac{\cos^{-1} (x)} {x}$$

I want to find the derivative of this function using the first principle method.

EDIT: for those who dont understand what is First principle method, may be you call it something else, it looks like this:

$$\frac{∆y}{∆x} = \lim_{∆x\to 0} \frac{f(x+∆x)-f(x)}{∆x}$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean: “from first principles”? As in, without using known formulae and using only the limit definition?

Comment: What is "the first principle method"?

Comment: @FShrike yes, without using the known formulas of differentiation, I'll edit my question to be more clear about first principle method

Comment: Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: You should really say “from first principles” and highlight which principles you consider to be “first”

Comment: @Buraian I tried solving but it didn't solve, It has a cos inverse function that is why Im stuck, I can find derivatives of normal trigonometric functions but not inverse functions. It gets more complicated.

Comment: You should show how far you got , where you got stuck.. so we know that we are really helping a person who is in **need of help** rather than one who is lazy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have a quotient between tho functions, hence you will apply the general rule for the quotient:

$$f(x) = \dfrac{g(x)}{h(x)}$$

hence we can compute the incremental ratio:

$$
\begin{split}
f'(x) &= \lim_{k\to 0} \frac{f(x+k) - f(x)}{k} \\\\
   &= \lim_{k\to 0} \frac{\frac{g(x+k)}{h(x+k)} - \frac{g(x)}{h(x)}}{k} \\\\
   &= \lim_{k\to 0} \frac{g(x+k)h(x) - g(x)h(x+k)}{k \cdot h(x)h(x+k)} \\\\
   &= \lim_{k\to 0} \frac{g(x+k)h(x) - g(x)h(x+k)}{k} \cdot \lim_{k\to 0}\frac{1}{h(x)h(x+k)} \\\\
   &= \left(\lim_{k\to 0} \frac{g(x+k)h(x) - g(x)h(x) + g(x)h(x) - g(x)h(x+k)}{k} \right) \cdot \frac{1}{h(x)^2} \\\\
   &= \left(\lim_{k\to 0} \frac{g(x+k)h(x) - g(x)h(x)}{k} - \lim_{k\to 0}\frac{g(x)h(x+k) - g(x)h(x)}{k} \right) \cdot \frac{1}{h(x)^2} \\\\
   &= \left(h(x)\lim_{k\to 0} \frac{g(x+k) - g(x)}{k} - g(x)\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{h(x+k) - h(x)}{k} \right) \cdot \frac{1}{h(x)^2} \\\\
   &= \frac{g'(x)h(x) - g(x)h'(x)}{h(x)^2}
\end{split}
$$

Now the problem reduces to find the derivatives of the single functions $g(x) = \arccos(x)$ and $h(x) = x$.

The second one is trivial, if you apply the formal definition you will get $1$ (you can do this).

The other one is a bit tricky but not difficult.

Thence we have

$$g(x) = \arccos(x)$$

We can then write $$\cos(g(x)) = x$$

Now we take the derivative of both sides (this could be another proof, but I bet you can prove what is the derivative of the cosine function):

$$-\sin(g(x))g'(x) = 1$$

Hence

$$g'(x) = \dfrac{-1}{\sin(g(x))} = \dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{1 - \cos^2(g(x))}} = -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

For at the beginning we had $\cos(g(x)) = x$.

What we conclude here is that

$$g'(x) = -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
$$h'(x) = 1$$

Now just plug and play into the quotient rule we got above, and you will get the derivative of your function, which by the way must result in being

$$f'(x) = -\frac{1}{x \sqrt{1-x^2}}-\frac{\cos ^{-1}(x)}{x^2}$$